# OrientDB doesn't drop property

Tags: orientdb

I'm not able to drop a property from a class. The error says that the property can not be found in class. But the property is there for sure.

[image: a busy cat]

I've tried to drop the property with command 'DROP PROPERTY VResearchInstitution.turnover' and also from OrientDB studio.

I want to drop the property from that class and add it back with other Data Type, from STRING to EMBEDDEDLIST. I know there should be a way to ALTER property and modify the type, but I'm not able to do that too, that's why I'm trying to delete it and add it back.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that only Node/Vertex with SuperClass seted has this behaviour. If someone has a better answer please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably making a small mistake somewhere else, something like a typo.

Consider the following code, which works without errors (you can try yourself):

```sql
/* Let's create a class TEST that has V as superclass */
CREATE CLASS TEST EXTENDS V
/* Let's create a class EXAMPLE that has TEST as superclass */
CREATE CLASS EXAMPLE EXTENDS TEST
/* Let's create a property */
CREATE PROPERTY EXAMPLE.Name STRING
/* Now let's delete the property */
DROP PROPERTY EXAMPLE.Name
/* EXAMPLE.name has been deleted successfully */

/* Now let's try altering the property */
CREATE PROPERTY EXAMPLE.Name STRING
ALTER PROPERTY EXAMPLE.Name MANDATORY TRUE
/* EXAMPLE.name has been altered successfully */
```

This works as expected. Beware of the following things when dropping properties:

- OrientDB is case-sensitive! In the above example, `DROP PROPERTY EXAMPLE.name` would give an error, so make sure that your query doesn't contain any typo's.
- Dropping properties *does not* delete data. Consider the following:

```sql
/* Let's add a vertex */
CREATE VERTEX EXAMPLE SET Name = 'a'

/* Now let's try deleting the property */
DROP PROPERTY EXAMPLE.Name

/* Now let's query the vertex */
SELECT FROM EXAMPLE WHERE Name = 'a'
```

The result will still contain the property `Name = 'a'` because dropping the property of a class only changes the `schema` of the class, but since [OrientDB's classes are schema-less](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/datamodeling/Concepts.html#class), your data is retained.

Hope that helps you find the bug.